# Code doesn't conform to picker view protocols. Problems using UIAlertControllerStyle

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I'm new to Swift coding but have used C++ and other languages but I keep getting the "does not conform" error on the line:

```
class CaloriesInputViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate , UITextFieldDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource`
```

Also, further down where ever it says `UIAlertControllerStyle` I keep getting an:

> "Extra argument 'message' in call"

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class CaloriesInputViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate , UITextFieldDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource{
    //Properties for food input detail
    @IBOutlet weak var foodName: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var caloriesAmount: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var pickerView: UIPickerView!

    var mealType: String = ""

    var pickerDataSource = ["Breakfast", "Lunch", "Dinner", "Snacks"];

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
        self.pickerView.dataSource = self
        self.pickerView.delegate = self

        initializeTextFields()
    }

    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return pickerDataSource.count;
    }

    private func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
        return pickerDataSource[row]
    }

    private func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)
    {
        if(row == 0)//Breakfast
        {
            mealType = "Breakfast"
        }
        else if(row == 1)//Lunch
        {
            mealType = "Lunch"
        }
        else if(row == 2)//Dinner
        {
            mealType = "Dinner"
        }
        else//Snacks
        {
            mealType = "Snacks"
        }
    }

    //Function to food details
    @IBAction func addCalories(sender: AnyObject) {
        if(foodName.text!.isEmpty || (caloriesAmount.text!.isEmpty) || mealType.isEmpty){
            //Output an Alert
            var alert = UIAlertControllerStyle(title: "Data Required", message: "Please enter all required information", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
            alert.show()

        }
        else{
            //Create a foodLog object in Parse
            var foodLog = PFObject(className: "foodLog")

            //Put user food detail into foodLog
            foodLog["foodName"] = foodName.text
            foodLog["caloriesCount"] = caloriesAmount.text
            foodLog["mealType"] = mealType
            foodLog["user"] = PFUser.current()!

            //Save data
            foodLog.saveInBackground()

            //Output an alert informing a user that the password or username did not meet the requirements
            var alert = UIAlertControllerStyle(title: "Recorded", message: "Your calories were recorded", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
            alert.show()

            //Redirect a user to a log view controller
            self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You seem to be trying to use the deprecated `UIAlertView`, in which case your code should be `var alert = UIAlertView(title: "Recorded", message: "Your calories were recorded", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")`, but you should really be using [`UIAlertController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uialertcontroller) for new code.

Comment: You have a lot of outdated Swift 2 code in there. You need to be using the proper signatures for the picker view methods.

Answer (score 0):

You mus use this code for your alertView :
Just add your code in completion handler, I don't understand what you want to do after the alert…

```
DispatchQueue.main.async() { () -> Void in


    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Recorded",
                                            message: "Your calories were recorded",
                                            preferredStyle: .alert)

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel",
                                     style: .cancel,
                                     handler: { _ in } )

    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)


    self.present(alertController,
                 animated: true,
               completion:nil)
}
```

Comment: Why is this code wrapped in `DispatchQueue.main.async` ? The code is in a (presumably) button handler which will only be called on the main queue.

Comment: And this answer only solves half of the question's issues.

Comment: hi, basically im making a calorie counter app, and this swift file is the only one thats giving me a error, i followed what my tutor said but i have no idea how to solve this problem, if you want i can upload the app files on googledrive and send you the link if it would help

Comment: hi, i can help you, let me see your file on google if you want. GitHub may be a better solution. Do your best and I can give you my feed back…